# Number puzzle! Find "?"

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Replace the question marks.

**1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, ?, 11, 14, 19, 20, ?**

Answer (score 3):

This is

> the number of nonprime numbers less than the nth prime (also known as sequence [A014689](http://oeis.org/A014689)).

The missing numbers are:

> 10 and 25.